# Why do we need Downcasting really?

Tags: java, downcast

I am trying to figure out why do I need Downcasting. I reread my notes from collage and found the below example.

```
class Student {...}

class Graduate exteds Student {
   getResearchTopic(){...} // this method only exists in Graduate class.
}
```

We have a ref to Student class and want to access to getResearchTopic method;

```
Student s1 = new Graduate();
if(s1 instanceof Graduate){
   ((Graduate)s1).getResearchTopic();
}
```

Great example for Downcasting hah? My question is Why not declare s1 as a Graduate in the first place? Is there a real life example where I will have to downcast instead of using an instance of actual class?

Comment: I would say that using downcasting in this case looks like a design issue in the application. One of the places where you **must** use downcasting is when overriding the `equals` method (as shown in the possible dup question).

Comment: I was about to post an answer =\ took too long anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could have declared the reference `s1` to be of type `Graduate`. The main benefit you get by declaring the reference of `super type`, is the power of *polymorphism*.

With a super type reference, pointing to a sub class object, you can bind the same reference to multiple sub class objects. And the actual method invoked will be decided at runtime, based on what object is being pointed to. But, the main condition for this is, *that method should also be defined in the subclass*, else the *compiler* will fail to find the method declaration.

Here, you were forced to `downcast`, because you haven't defined the method in the super class. As compiler cannot see the definition of that method in `Student` class. It has no idea about what the actual object `s1` points to. Remember, compiler only checks the reference type to find the meethod declaration.

In general, whenever you see yourself downcasting to a subclass in your code, it is almost always a sign a something wrong (there are some exceptions though). And you should modify your classes.

---

Let's see what benefit you get by using a super class reference instead of a subclass reference:

For e.g: Suppose you have another sub class of `Student` as:

```
class Phd extends Student {
    getResearchTopic(){...}
}
```

and you also provide a definition (a default one) in `Student` class:

```
class Student {
    getResearchTopic(){...}
}
```

Now, you create a following two objects, both being pointed to by `Student` reference:

```
Student student = new Phd();
student.getResearchTopic();   // Calls Phd class method

student = new Graduate();
student.getResearchTopic();    // Calls Graduate class method
```

So, with only a single reference, you get to access methods specific to subclasses.

---

One major implementation of this feature you can see in `factory method` pattern, where a single static method returns an object of different sub classes based on some condition:

```
public static Student getInstance(String type) {
    if (type.equals("graduate")) 
        return new Graduate();
    else if (type.equals("phd"))
        return new Phd();
}
```

So, you can see that the same method returns an object of different subclasses.

All of the above stuffs you can do just because of one concept:

*A Super class reference can refer to any sub class objects, but not vice-versa*.

Comment: *Why not declare s1 as a Graduate in the first place* This is main OP's concern, probably you want to expand the answer to solve this part.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza John. Sorry, I misread the question earlier. Edited it now.

Comment: In fact, using downcasting degrades the *power of polymorphism*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Yeah, right. I've expanded my answer to explain the general concept.

Answer (score 6):

Say you have a method that takes a `Student` as a parameter.  Most of the things it does are generic for all students. But if it is a `Graduate` there might be something else it does as well.  In that case you would need to determine if the `Student` passed in was actually a `Graduate` and do some special logic in that instance.

Maybe something like this:

```
class StudentDAO {
    public void SaveStudent(Student s) {
       // Do something to save the student data to a database.

       if ( s instanceof Graduate ) {
           // Save their research topic too.
       }
    }
}
```

Note that doing that kind of thing is usually a poor programming practice, but sometimes it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you deserialize an object using the default Java deserializer, you use this code (and you use analogous code when using another deserializer, e.g. the Jackson JSON deserializer)

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
Object obj = ois.readObject();
```

You then need to cast `obj` to its actual type, because `readObject()` will always return a plain old `Object` - the method can't statically verify what sort of object is being read

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you want to use polymorphism, it would be nice to work with `Student` objects, and then "downcast" to use methods specific to `Graduate` objects.

In general, if you have a method that works with `Student` objects, that method don't really know at compile-time what specific type of `Student` objects are passed in.  Thus, at run-time, the method should check for the specific type and process accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Downcasting does help when you're trying to make generic methods.  For example, I often see code that parses an XML `String` into an `Object`.  The `Object` can then be downcast into the specific `Object` that you (as the coder) know it represents.

```
private static XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
static {
    xstream.processAnnotations(MyFirstClass.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(MySecondClass.class);
    // ...
}

public static Object fromXML(String xml) {
    return xstream.fromXML(xml);
}
```

This lets me make a very generic method which does what I want it to do in all cases.  Then, when I call it, I can simply downcast the `Object` into what I know it's going to be.  It prevents me from having to make a separate parse method for every object type and improves the readability of my code.

```
MyFirstClass parsedObject = (MyFirstClass) MyXMLTransformer.fromXML(xml);
```

Comment: In your case, you can redefine the method as `private <T> T fromXml(String xml, Class<T> clazz)` and make it a real generic method, thus avoiding the downcasting problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I suppose that's true as well. :)  Good point.